# rsync: failed to connect to 1.2.3.4\#015: Connection refused

Tags: bash, syntax, rsync, carriage-return

I wanted to create a simple bash script to read IPs from a text file and run the following command to discover rsync service enabled IPs:

```
 rsync -av 1.2.3.4:: .
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
   name="$line"
   echo "Target: $name"
   rsync -av $name:: .
done < "$filename"
```

It does not seem to be working.
Both the above scripts gave the following error:

```
rsync: failed to connect to 1.2.3.4\#015: Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(122) [Receiver=3.0.7]
```

Comment: `\#015` is possibly the carriage return symbol that you have got clinging to the end of the IP-address when read from the file. Can you make sure that the file has correct UNIX line ends with `dos2unix`?

Comment: I edited your question to better focus on the actual problem.  Please review.  Also what do you mean by "both the above scripts"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest first to remove carriage returns:

```
dos2unix "$filename"
```

or use:

```
dos2unix < "$filename" | while read -r line
do
   ...
done
```